# setting up multiple (dual primary) hosted dns providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, managed, ddos

I think I may be overcomplicating the following issue so seeking some advice.

I am using Dyn as my sole hosted DNS provider. Due to recent events I am now looking to distribute it over multiple providers to allow for redundancy should this happen again.

Instead of using Dyn as a primary and say Route 53 as a failover should Dyn go down, what I want is both Dyn and Route 53 as primary DNS' - dual primary if you will.

Now I realise there may be some issues with keeping both services in sync, and there isn't a huge amount of info on either provider's websites on this issue.

An [article on Dyn's blog](http://dyn.com/blog/crouching-tiger-hidden-master-a-look-at-the-primary-secondary-dns-relationship/) mentions this scenario but doesn't go into a huge amount of detail, as does [this article on Medium](https://medium.com/@brianarmstrong/youre-probably-doing-dns-wrong-like-we-were-6625efaed390#.2uq1zjgb8).

My question being is it just as simple as mirroring ns records of both providers. So on your Dyn DNS just add your Route 53 ns records to an existing zone and vice versa on your Route 53 console?

Any advice from anyone who's set something like this up before would be really appreciated.

Also any arguments for / against this method over say a primary / secondary setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it just as simple as mirroring ns records of both providers

The NS records will need to be updated, but those aren't what determines which nameservers the Internet considers authoritative for your domain.

You will need to update the authoritative name servers with your domain registrar.  That's the change that actually makes this work.

Other than that, it's pretty straightforward.  The Internet has no concept of who your authoritative DNS *provider* is -- only which *nameservers* are authoritative.  The fact that those nameservers are owned by a combination of providers doesn't matter.

Note that this configuration will prevent you from using a number of the features of Route 53, such as A-record aliases, latency-based routing, and DNS responses that are driven by other factors like health checks.

Comment: Thanks for this, pretty much got to the same conclusion but good to clarify